# A function for finding n consecutive characters returning true/false

Tags: c++, boolean

I want to have a function that is going return true if and only if when `char*` s contains sequence of n consecutive identical signs. For example if we have `"aaac"` and `n=3` i want the function to return true.

My idea for the code is:

```
bool g(char* s, int n){
    if(s[0]==0) return true;
    for (int i=0; s[i+1]!=0;i++){
        for (int j=i; s[i+1]!=0;j++){
         while(int a != n){
            if(s[i]==s[i+j]){
             a++;
            }
         }
        }  
    } 
}
int main() {
    cout<< g("aaac",3);
}
```

I know that the code is incomplete however the problem is that i do not know where do i need to  `return true` and where to put `return false`.

**PLEASE** rather then down voting this question please explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: to check whether it is not empty? And in for loops to go till the end of char.

Comment: `int a != n`... wow.

Comment: What should be the result for `"aaac"` and `n=2` ?

Comment: True as you have two a's in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is needlessly complex. You can do it with a single loop, like this:

- Make a counter, and set it to zero
- Examine each pair of consecutive characters, i.e. `*s` and `*(s+1)`
- If they are *not* the same, set counter to zero
- Otherwise, increment the counter; if it reaches `n`, return `true`.
- If you reach the end of the loop, when `s` points to null terminator, return `false`.

Checking the difference can be done like this:

```
if (*(s+1) == *s) {
    count++;
    if (count == n) {
        return true;
    }
} else {
    count = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for an answer.